# How to come back to previous revision at server ? (GIT)

Tags: git, github

my last commits list :

**commit-hash, message**

```
fc690d2c3   come back
da645f048   code refactoring = 10%
38cababf0   refactoring application from imports
```

so its mean fc690d2c3 is HEAD revision on server.
i need come back to this -> "38cababf0" revision.

I was trying to do smth like this:
`git reset --hard 38cababf0` -> but it only my local revision becomes 38cababf0 ( remove revision still fc690d2c3), and i cant push this because it does not see changes

and i was trying to revert in PyCharm, from da645f048 to 38cababf0 revision, but it just commit my da645f048 revision again as fc690d2c3

so how come back to this 38cababf0 revision on server?

Answer (score 0):

If these changes are already on the server your best bet is to just revert them like this:

```
git revert da645f048..fc690d2c3
```

That will create new commits that reverse the changes of the commits you don't want anymore.